# Python: wx.ListCtrl -> how to make one of the items a picture that once clicked opens a file

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wx.ListCtrl instance to which I use InsertColumn like this:

Path | Size | ... | Last run

For each item to be displayed I have a function that sets all the fields: 
setStringItem(index, 0, path)
setStringItem(index, 1, size)
...

I want on column 6 (Last run) to do the following:
1) add a picture
2) the picture should be clickable, once clicked it should open a file

For pictures I use PyEmbeddedImage (using img2py) like this:
btn_remove_entry = GenBitmapTextButton(self, -1,
         remove_img.GetBitmap(), "text", size=(120, 35)    )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Andrea's [UltimateListCtrl](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/main/UltimateListCtrl.html) - it's included in the latest wx, but the online docs aren't up to date.

Comment: See http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/AGW_Docs/ultimatelistctrl_module.html#ultimatelistctrl